# How to save the output as a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to save the output as a text file on my system. The name of the output file should get from the user in command prompt.

```
   output = input("Enter a name for output file:")    

   my_file = open('/output.txt', "w") 

    for i in range(1, 10):
       my_file.write(i)
```

Is this correct way of doing??

Comment: Right now you're writing to a file literally named `output.txt`. If you want to use the user's input as the file name, you'll have to pass something like `output + '.txt'` to the `open` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import os

# you can use input() if it's python 3
output = raw_input("Enter a name for output file:")

with open("{}\{}.txt".format(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), output), "w") as my_file:
    for i in range(1, 10):
        my_file.write("".format(i))
```

At this example we are using the local path by using `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` we will get the current path and we will add it `output.txt`

1. To read more about `abspath()` look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)
2. To read more about with look [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)
3. `write` method in you case will raise a TypeError since `i` needs to be a `string`

Comment: Down-voter can you explain your down-vote so i can improve the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Do like this

```
output = raw_input("Enter a name for output file:")    
my_file = open(output + '.txt', "w") 
for i in range(1, 10):
    my_file.write(str(i))
```

Comment: It will not work since TypeError will be raised at the `write` method, you need to write str.

Answer (score 0):

So couple of changes I made. You need to do something like:

```
    output + '.txt'
```

to use the variable output as the file name.

Apart from that, you need to convert the integer i to a string by calling the str() function:

```
    str(i)
```

becuase the write function only takes strings as input.

**Here is the code all together:**

```
    output = raw_input("Enter a name for output file: ")    

    my_file = open(output + '.txt', 'wb') 

    for i in range(1, 10):
        my_file.write(str(i))

    my_file.close()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line so you will have your txt file in your `.py` file path:

```
 my_file=open('{}.txt'.format(input('enter your name:')),'w')
 for i in range(1, 10):
    my_file.write(str(i))
 my_file.close()
```

Note: if you are using `python 2.x` use `raw_input()` instead of `input` .